# Getting Sorry, this action is not available in simulation for a Google Assistant App?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

Even after using the phrase

> Talk to Abhijit Kar

I keep getting: this action is not available in simulation

I have verified the google account as well.
I arrived at the test page using Test Draft Button.

Comment: You've tagged this with google-assistant-sdk, is this a Smart Home app? Can you update your question to show screen shots of the test simulator, and particularly the debug tab?

Comment: Can you instead try "talk to my test app"?

Comment: Thanks Nick Felker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Nick Felker, I understood that whatever the app's name maybe, in this case **Abhijit**.

For testing we need to say **talk to my test app**.